# Why does allocating temporary pointers seem to be causing stack overflow?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, lifetime, temporary-objects

In the example below, when using GCC version 4.3.3 based target powerpc compiler, it seems every `Add` method call increases the used size of the stack. What I have known until today is that,
after that `Add` method is called, that temporary variable should have been released (I mean the temporary pointer, not the object).

```
ClassA* pContainer = new ClassA(paramsA);
{
    pContainer->Add(new ClassB(paramsB1)); // Stack size increases
    pContainer->Add(new ClassB(paramsB2)); // Stack size increases
    ... 
    pContainer->Add(new ClassB(paramsBN)); // Stack size increases. (If size is many, it causes stack overflow)
}
// stack size probably (not well tested yet) OK here
```

In Windows, with Visual Studio 2012, it works as I expected, which the stack size returns back to its previous size after the call.

Do you have any idea?

Signature of Add:

```
void ClassA::Add(ClassB* pObject);
```

Following code does not produce a stack overflow error:

```
ClassA* pContainer = new ClassA(paramsA);
ClassB* pItem = NULL;
{
    pItem = new ClassB(paramsB1);
    pContainer->Add(pItem); // Stack size same
    pItem = new ClassB(paramsB2);
    pContainer->Add(pItem); // Stack size same
    ... 
    pItem = new ClassB(paramsBN);
    pContainer->Add(pItem); // Stack size same.
}
```

Comment: I assume Add() is not taking a parameter as strange as const ClassB*& , right? The only exception i could think of would be the binding to a const lvalue reference, in which case the compiler may extend the lifetime.

Comment: Did you really encountered stack overflow? Maybe it's not necessery (deletion of temporary pointers) as long as you do not come close to the stackframe limit? Try to achieve stack overflow state.

Comment: What's the signature of `ClassA::Add`?

Comment: Not enough code provided. Implementation of Add may vary depending on OS

Comment: How are you determining the stack size?

Comment: Added signature of Add method

Comment: Value of Stack Pointer Register is the reference for me to determine stack size.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations? Are you sure `Add` is not bugged?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not seen any error by myself or using any static analysis tool I have in Add method implementation. Optimizations are disabled.

Comment: I have added detail I remember.